# Eclipse conio.h resolving error

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, intel-edison

I am working on the Intel Edison and using Eclipse Kepler as the `IDE` with Intel system studio as the toolchain.
However a certain rather major program requires the header file `conio.h` which is not included and therefore giving me a `catastrophic error`. This hampers my program execution.
Please suggest a remedy or an alternate replacement.

Comment: Which functions of `conio.h` do you need? Which OS are you using?

Comment: conio.h sounds like 20 old turbo c.

Comment: The first hit on Google is a Wikipedia page with pretty much everything there is to know.

Comment: I want to declare a file object and read and write data to it ( primarily using functions like fprintf, fscanf etc ). Although stdio.h should do the job,  but i'm still getting an error while building it.

Answer (score 0):

> Please suggest a remedy or an alternate replacement.

There is no alternate replacement, as conio.h is a non-standard header.

This means you will probably have to either create one yourself and add in it whatever symbols you are using from conio.h, or replace any APIs you are using from conio.h with other alternatives.

**Edit**: [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) describes the typical things one might expect to find in conio.h.